# Field jdbcTemplate in com.lrl.abc.service.abc required a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

I have created spring boot application to create restful Api. I have Postgres db on AWS so i want to connect to it and perform crud operations.
I have done following some article but now hitting the Jdbc DataSource error. following is the code:

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://abc.awe.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/test_db
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=***********
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
```

AbcService

```
 @Service
 public class AbcService {
     @Autowired
     private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

     @Autowired
     public AbcService(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
         this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
     }
```

Using it like this

```
String result = this.jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(
                     "select name from table where id=?",
                     String.class,
                     id
             );
```

Tried with config file like this

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    @Bean
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }
}
```

Still I get below error:

```
 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean 
with name 'abcService' defined in file 
[/code/build/classes/java/main/com/lrl/abcService/service/abcService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0: 
No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' available: 
expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
{}

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of constructor in 
com.lrl.abcService.service.AbcService required a bean 
of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' in your 
configuration.
```

Can you help what i am missing here!

Comment: Isn't one Autowired too many in AbcService? It should be enough to mark the constructor with Autowired.  And the configuration of DataSourceConfig should also be superfluous.

Comment: Sorry that was by mistake i only have Autowired only for constructor! Still the same error

Comment: Can you add a breakpoint on the the configuration class in the method that instantiates the JdbcTemplate and check 2 things 1- whether the methods is being called, 2- whether the DataSource is already set? I think the latter is null hence jdbcTemplate not being started.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, do you have mysql-connector-java dependency? Also, you could try setting/hardcoding the DataSource values like dataSource.setURL().